# Custom HTML Advanced Issue

Tags: joomla-3.4

I am attempting to port a Javascript searchable membership roster (name address, etc) from my HTML site to a new Joomla 3.4 site. The Javascript (created by Satadip Dutta) in embeded in the HTML file. The file works perfectly in the HTML site and it works perfectly in Joomla, EXCEPT when I enter more than 166 member information (I have about 340 members).

When attempting to enter the code in Custom HTML Advanced with more than 166 member's info, I cannot save the the HTML code in the Custom HTML Advanced module. There is no coding errors as I am doing a copy and paste into Custom HTML Advanced and once I discovered the issue I added/removed member information one at a time until it broke.

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced) to add your code.

The `textarea` field used to enter your code in this module has a limit as to how much data can be included (about 50KB), so if your Javascript and member's info is very long, that might be the cause. You can use [this tool](http://bytesizematters.com/) to check the size of your data.

I suggest you place parts of the Javascript in an external `.js` file, and load it (you can use Custom HTML Advanced for this if you like).

```
<script src="path/to/your/js/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a big static piece of HTML, it would be better to paste it into an article (Editor Off).

You can also implement a specific module oriented to add source code, JED [Coding & Scripts Integration](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration)  (e.g. NoNumber's sourcerer). Joomla Custom Html module applies certain filters that may block your code.